# mouse over event on an MVVM individual objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am wondering on the best way of dealing with a problem I have.
I am in the early stages developing a WPF application that has several images that are all 
individual classes. I am attempting to use the MVVM model but I wish to implement a Mouse over event such that when I scroll over a image I wish to bring up some information or do some effects over the image I am not quite sure how to go around this but I have an example of the class below.

```
public class TeamKit
{
    private Image mainImage;
    public Canvas Position { get; set; }
    public TextBlock PlayerText { get; set; }
    public TextBlock NameText{ get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }
    private string _playerName = "Player0";
    private string _playerNumber = "0";
    private BitmapImage _bImage;

    public TeamKit(Thickness t)
    {
        mainImage = new Image();
        _bImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://Application:,,,/Resources/KitC.png"));
        mainImage.Source = _bImage;
        mainImage.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;
        Position = new Canvas();
        Position.Width = 38;
        Position.Height = 45;
        Position.Margin = t;
        mainImage.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 6);

        PlayerText = new TextBlock();
        PlayerText.Text = ""; PlayerText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        PlayerText.Margin = new Thickness(11, 15, 27, 15);

        Position.Children.Add(mainImage);
        Position.Children.Add(PlayerText);
    }

    public TeamKit()
    {
        mainImage = new Image();
        _bImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://Application:,,,/Resources/KitC.png"));
        mainImage.Source = _bImage;
        mainImage.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;
        Position = new Canvas();
        Position.Width = 38;
        Position.Height = 45;
        //mainImage.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 6);

        PlayerText = new TextBlock();
        PlayerText.Text = _playerNumber; PlayerText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        PlayerText.Margin = new Thickness(12, 15, 27, 15);
        PlayerText.Width = 15;

        Viewbox Vb = new Viewbox();
        //Vb.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;
        Vb.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Uniform;
        Vb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        Canvas.SetTop(Vb, 40);
        Canvas.SetLeft(Vb, -11);
        Vb.MaxWidth = 50;

        NameText = new TextBlock();
        NameText.Text = _playerName;
        NameText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        NameText.MaxHeight = 40;
        NameText.MaxWidth = 90;

        Vb.Child = NameText;
        Position.Children.Add(Vb);
         //<TextBlock Text="FooAlanghi" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" MaxHeight="40" MaxWidth="92" />


        Position.Children.Add(mainImage);
        Position.Children.Add(PlayerText);
    }

    public TeamKit(Player Player, int PlayerNumber)
    {
        this.Player = Player;
        _playerNumber = PlayerNumber.ToString();
        _playerName = Player.Last_Name;

        mainImage = new Image();
        _bImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://Application:,,,/Resources/KitC.png"));
        mainImage.Source = _bImage;
        mainImage.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;
        Position = new Canvas();
        Position.Width = 38;
        Position.Height = 45;
        //mainImage.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 6);

        PlayerText = new TextBlock();
        PlayerText.Text = _playerNumber; PlayerText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        PlayerText.Margin = new Thickness(12, 15, 27, 15);
        PlayerText.Width = 15;

        Viewbox Vb = new Viewbox();
        //Vb.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;
        Vb.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Uniform;
        Vb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        Canvas.SetTop(Vb, 40);
        Canvas.SetLeft(Vb, -11);
        Vb.MaxWidth = 50;

        NameText = new TextBlock();
        NameText.Text = _playerName;
        NameText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        NameText.MaxHeight = 40;
        NameText.MaxWidth = 90;

        Vb.Child = NameText;
        Position.Children.Add(Vb);
        //<TextBlock Text="FooAlanghi" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" MaxHeight="40" MaxWidth="92" />


        Position.Children.Add(mainImage);
        Position.Children.Add(PlayerText);
    }


    public void Add(Panel Parent)
    {
        Parent.Children.Add(this.Position);
    }

    public static void DrawPositionLineUp(List<TeamKit> Players, Panel panel, double top, double left)
    {
        double ix = 0;
        foreach (TeamKit t in Players)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(t.Position, left);
            Canvas.SetTop(t.Position, ix += top);
            t.Add(panel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nice that you're using the MVVM route, but be aware that what you are wanting to do has nothing to do with MVVM. You're question is all view-related (well, mostly).

You're control needs a [`ToolTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.aspx):

```
<Image ...>
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip ...>
            Content (which can be another layout of controls)
        </ToolTip>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

As for effects, depending on *what* effects, a lot of them are already built in (blur, shadow, etc). But, either way you want to use Triggers within the style.

```
<Image ...>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style>
            <Trigger Property="Image.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter ... /> <!-- Apply Styles Here -->
            </Trigger>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

NOTE: It's probably best to pull out the style into a static resource and apply it to all controls of that kind within that Window/User Control/Page or higher up in the chain (Application) so that you can do...

```
<Image Style="{StaticResource MouseOverImage}" ... />
```

---

As for why I said "you're question is all view-related (well, mostly)" ... what I mean is that it is view-related up until the point of databinding, then you must coordinate with your view-model to make sure it exposes properties that you need. Outside of that, it is a 100% view-related question and you do not have to worry about any MVVMness in this situation. Continue using MVVM, but realize that this is how you'd do it whether or not you were using MVVM.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using triggers?
When handling mouseover events I usually go with triggers, but you should also consider [MVVM light](http://galasoft.ch/mvvm/) - (or something similar)  its a great tool for MVVM enthusiasts.

Comment: Triggers is definately something to look into but unfortunately due to the environment constraints I cannot install anything that is not on-board

Comment: @LukeShoge [Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx) are a built-in part of WPF